# Accessing File Modified Date in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, apache2, last-modified

Is it possible to get access to file attributes such as when a file was created or last modified?

I have cached gzip files, and would like to be able to set a last-modified header to them. Something like:

```
<If CLIENT CAN HANDLE GZIP && IN DIRECTORY CACHE/HTML/>
    Header Set Last-Modified {WHEN-FILE-WAS-LAST-MODIFIED}
</If>
```

Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: _"Or is there some other way of doing this?"_ Depends, what do you need it for? Basically what is the purpose?

Comment: I have gzipped files of raw HTML pages - a cache to save my server creating these pages for each request. I'd like to be able to send a Last-Modified header with these gzipped HTML files. I know this could be done with PHP, but I'd rather avoid that.